# Acessing Soundcloud Recommendations via HTTP API

Tags: api, soundcloud, recommendation-engine

I was wondering if soundcloud can make any recommendations to a user, based on the previous history.
Specifically, I want to integrate that in my application. Following this https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference , I couldnt find any